# array problem of finding number of edits needed

Tags: c++, arrays, minimum

Given an array arr containing positive elements and an integer K. In one operation you can pick an element of the array (suppose arr[i]) & break to p1,p2 insert p1 & p2. You need to find the minimum possible value.

This is my approach:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;
int main(){
int n,k; cin >> n >> k;
vector<int>v;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    int x; cin >> x;
    v.push_back(x);
}
while(k--)
{
    int x,y;
    sort(v.begin(),v.end());
    int p=v[v.size()-1];
    vector<int>::iterator it;
    it=v.begin()+v.size()-1; 
    v.erase(it);
    if(p%2==0)
    {
        x=p/2,y=p/2;
    }
    else
    {
        x=p/2;
        y=p-x;
    }
    v.push_back(x);
    v.push_back(y);
}
cout << *max_element(v.begin(),v.end());
return 0;
}
```

Is it correct? If it is correct then (TC is n*k) is there any optimized solution possible?

Comment: The code has includes and main wrapping missing. Please post working code

Comment: This algorithm is incorrect. Given a list containing the single item 12 and a limit of two operations, it would break it into 6 and 6, and then 6, 3, and 3. But the optimal solution would be 4 and 8 and then 4, 4, and 4.

Comment: @EricPostpischil then could u please tell me some edits to make it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already stated in a comment, your algorithm cannot always provide the correct answer. This is a proposal of another algorithm.

Checking that a given max (= target) can be obtained in `K` operations is rather easy: for each element `x=A[i]`, calculate the number of operations `C(x)` which are necessary for this particular element to become less than the target. The total number of needed operations is equal to the sum of the individual counts. We just have to compare the total obtained with `K`.

For example, `C(x)  = sup(x/target) -1`, when `sup(.)` is equal to the lowest integer higher or equal than its input value. Just pay attention that `C(0) = 0`.

This checking of the validity of the target value can be optimised by sorting the array in decreasing order. This allows to stop the count when the array element becomes less than the target.

The minimum maximum value `minmax` is such that `minmax` can be validated by the above procedure, but not `minmax-1`. This can be performed by a binary search.

Global complexity: O(n log(Amax)), where Amax is the maximum element value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

int Count_elt (int x, int target) {
    if (x == 0) return 0;
    int count = x/target;
    if (target*count == x) count --;
    return count;
}

bool check_target (std::vector<int>& A, int K, int target) {
    int n = A.size();
    int count = 0;
    for (int val: A) {
        if ((val <= target) || count > K) break;
        count += Count_elt (val, target);
    }
    return count <= K;
}

int minmax (std::vector<int>& A, int K) {
    std::sort (A.begin(), A.end(), std::greater<int>());
    if (A[0] == 0) return 0;
    int limit_0 = 0;    // highest value such that check = false
    int limit_1 = A[0]; // lowest value such that check = true
    while (true) {
        if (limit_1 == limit_0 + 1) return limit_1;
        int target = (limit_0 + limit_1) / 2;
        bool test = check_target(A, K, target);
        if (test) {
            limit_1 = target;
        } else {
            limit_0 = target;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main () {
    std::vector<int> A = {12, 3, 3, 9};
    int K = 3;
    int Count = minmax (A, K);
    std::cout << "Count = " << Count << "\n";
}
```

Comment: but the target isn't given in the question we have to minimize it.

Comment: Target is just an intermediate parameter that we can use in the binary search of the result

Comment: thanks you, I have a doubt on another problem can u share your email id?

Comment: If you have a similar problem, I would prefer that you post a new question. I am rather busy. Also, if you feel that  your problem is at the algorithm level, don't forget to add the algorithm tag. I will try to answer if I can.